# All prints in function with tabs. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to append '\t' to all prints in function?

Example:

```
def func():
   print('this print with tab')
   print('and this print with tab')

print('some text:')
func()
```

Output of the code should be:

```
some text:
   this print with tab
   and this print with tab
```

Output of the code `func()` should be without tabs:

```
this print with tab
and this print with tab
```

So, I think It should be something like decorator over func.

Comment: `print('\tStuff')`. What's the problem here?

Comment: No, because there are cases when i call func without additional print above. In these cases a want all prints in the function to be without tabs.

Comment: Then you should add an argument to `func` that would determine whether to print `'\t'` or not.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Maybe this task is solved using decorators.

Comment: No, decorators cannot alter the body of the function.

Comment: @ForceBru, you are right, they cannot alter the body, but they can manipulate the state of the method. Using vaultah's briliant `redirect_stdout` idea, I managed to implement such a decorator.

Comment: @ТолкачёвИван, I was inspired by vaultah's answer and implemented a decorator.

Comment: @DanielTrugman, please, add it to answers :)

Comment: @ТолкачёвИван, already added :) See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect STDOUT to a file-like object temporarily and call your function. Then read the entire contents of the buffer and call [`textwrap.indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent) to indent every line:

```
import io, textwrap
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

output = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(output):
    func()

print(textwrap.indent(output.getvalue(), '\t'), end='')
```

outputs

```
some text:
    this print with tab
    and this print with tab
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Use a separate method**

Define a method:

```
def tprint(*args, **kwargs):
  print('\t', *args, **kwargs)
```

and just call it instead of `print`

**Option 2: Use decorator**

Inspired by vaultah`s answer:

```
def maketabbed(func):
    def tabbed():
      output = io.StringIO()
      with contextlib.redirect_stdout(output):
        func()
      for line in output.getvalue().splitlines():
        print('\t' + line)
    return tabbed

@maketabbed
def func():
  print('this print with tab')
  print('and this print with tab')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a function that prepend a tab.

```
def myPrintTab(*msg):
    print("\t",*msg)
```

Then use it instead of print where you need.

Comment: This limits the print to a single string

Comment: yes but this is the basic idea, it can be refined by using varargs

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an optional argument that would trigger the `'\t'`:

```
def func(t=False):
   t = '\t' if t else ''
   print(t + 'this print with tab')
   print(t + 'and this print with tab')

print('some text:')
func(True)
```